# Wondering Why This JavaScript is Unresponsive in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, being as I know nothing about JavaScript, its probably obvious, but I still am at a loss here. Basically, I was coding a prisoner's dilemma game into HTML with JS, and it seems to not be working as it should be. Basically, all the code starting from the variables is as follows:

```
<div class="leftentry">
    <button id='button1'>Rat Them Out</button>
    <br>
    <button id='button2'>Keep Your Partner Safe</button>
    <script>
        var leftinput;
        leftinput = 0;
        $('#button1').on('click',left1);
        $('#button2').on('click', left2);

        function left1(){
        leftinput = 1;
        }
        function left2(){
        leftinput = 2;
        }

    </script>
</div>

    <div class="rightentry">
    <button id='button3'>Rat Them Out</button>
    <br>
    <button id='button4'>Keep Your Partner Safe</button>
    <script>
        var rightinput;
        rightinput = 0;
        $('#button3').on('click',right1);
        $('#button4').on('click',right2);

        function right1(){
        leftinput = 1;
        }
        function right2(){
        leftinput = 2;
        }

    </script>
</div>



        </h1>
        <center>
        <p>
            You and your partner in crime are busted, and are brought in for questioning. You aren't allowed to communicate, but you understand that if your stories match, you will get fewer years. Find a friend and try to stay out of jail! After each player makes a decision without the other's knowledge, click the COURT button below to see the results!
        </p>
        <br>
        <hr width="75%">
        <br>
        <button id='finaldecision'>Court</button>
        <br>
        <div id="leftgreater"  style="display:none" class="answer_list"><p>The left player rats out the right, with the latter getting stuck in jail for 3 years, and the former running off free.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="equal"  style="display:none" class="answer_list"><p>Neither player rats out the other, and they both get 1 year in prison.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="rightgreater"  style="display:none" class="answer_list"><p>The right player rats out the left, with the latter getting stuck in jail for 3 years, and the former running off free.</p>
        </div>
        <script>
            $('#finaldecision').on('click', final);

            function final(){
                if (leftinput > rightinput) {
                    document.getElementById('leftgreater').style.display = "block";
                } else if (leftinput == rightinput) {
                    document.getElementById('equal').style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('rightgreater').style.display = "block";
                }
            }
            function final(){
            document.getElementById('answer').style.display = "block";
            }
        </script>
```

It should allow each player to select a choice, and upon clicking "Court", it should run the code to reveal whatever is the decision, be it left, right, or equals.

Comment: While editing, please edit the title too. The title is supposed to describe the actual program problem at hands, not your experience while solving it. And the text should also describe the problem, "not working" doesn't describe anything. What you want your code to do, and what it does instead?

Comment: just some advice, we don't need the back story. Just post what you've tried (your code) and let us know what the error is

Comment: What exactly is your problem? And what do you expect from a working version?

Comment: @ZachGates It should allow each player to select a choice, and upon clicking "Court", it should run the code to reveal whatever is the decision, be it left, right, or equals.

Comment: In addition, Jquery is installed in header, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: whats the error? what have you tried via debugging?

Comment: Crazy question,  did you include jquery library

Comment: There are two `final` functions declared, the latter overrides the first function.

Comment: @Teemu I knew I was missing something!